# How can I specify a margin to a chapter reference link in HTML?

Tags: html, css, header, href, margin

I have a body with an header (100px), and a container with a magin (100px).
Like this :

```
.myHeader {
  height: 100px;
}

.myContainer {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

I'm writing some texts with chapters and i refers some chapters with a button.

```
<a href={`#${chapter.step}`}>
    <Button key={chapter.id} >
       {chapter.name}
    </Button>
</a>
```

On the text side, i have obviously a `<div id="chapterId">...text</div>`.

This works well, except the fact that the link leads me to the top of the page, behind the header.

How I can specify the reference to begin at a certain height ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can collect from your post, and I'm not sure I'm correct because you provided a somewhat vague information, you are trying to keep the container 100px from the top of the *window*, so that the header remains visible. Referring to the window boundaries usually requires `position: fixed;`. Here is an example that looks like what I think your description refers to:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.myHeader {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
  font: 50px/100px serif;
}

.myContainer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="myHeader">
  Header
</h2>
<section class="myContainer">
  <a href="#Chapter_2">Jump to Chapter 2</a>
  <h3 id="Chapter_1">Chapter 1</h3>
  Text of chapter 1. Text of chapter 1. Text of chapter 1. Text of chapter 1. Text of chapter 1. Text of chapter 1. Text of chapter 1. Text of chapter 1. Text of chapter 1. Text of chapter 1. Text of chapter 1. Text of chapter 1. Text of chapter 1. Text of chapter 1. Text of chapter 1. Text of chapter 1. Text of chapter 1. Text of chapter 1. Text of chapter 1. Text of chapter 1. Text of chapter 1. Text of chapter 1. 
  
  <h3 id="Chapter_2">Chapter 2</h3>
  Text of chapter 2. Text of chapter 2. Text of chapter 2. Text of chapter 2. Text of chapter 2. Text of chapter 2. Text of chapter 2. Text of chapter 2. Text of chapter 2. Text of chapter 2. Text of chapter 2. Text of chapter 2. Text of chapter 2. Text of chapter 2. Text of chapter 2. Text of chapter 2. Text of chapter 2. Text of chapter 2. Text of chapter 2. Text of chapter 2. Text of chapter 2. Text of chapter 2. Text of chapter 2. Text of chapter 2. Text of chapter 2. Text of chapter 2. 
</section>
```